# One-to-one relationship in EF

Tags: database, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

My models look the following:

```
public class Job
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual JobResult Result { get; set; }
}
public class JobResult
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Job")]
    public int JobId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual Job Job { get; set; }
}
```

As you see the relationship is a required one-to-one.
When I try to create and save a job:

```
Job job = new Job();
job.Result = new Result();
context.Jobs.add(job);
context.SaveChanges();
```

I get the following error:

> Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations.
>   Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model
>   requirements, or store-generated values.

I don't quite understand the error message. What does it mean and what could be causing this error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create a real one-to-one relationship in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292355/how-do-i-create-a-real-one-to-one-relationship-in-sql-server).  I'm pretty sure it is technically impossible in SQL Server to have a True 1 to 1 relationship, as that would mean you would have to insert both records at the same time (otherwise you'd get a contraint error on insert), in both tables, with both tables having a foreign key relationship to each other.

Comment: @ErikPhilips - He mentions in a comment below that it's actually 1:0..1 not 1:1, as JobResult is optional

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch the questions should have been updated, as all questions should be self sufficient and not require anyone to read comments or comments of answers.

Comment: @ErikPhilips - I agree, just pointing it out...

Answer (score 3):

Your case is not valid beacose this is a circular reference. What must be done EF:

1. INSERT INTO `JobResults(....., Job_Id)` VALUES `(....., @JobId);`

EF can not do this becase Job not inserted and does not have Id.

2. INSERT INTO `Jobs(....., JobResult_Id)` VALUES `(....., @JobResultId);`

EF as well can not do this becase JobResult not inserted and does not have Id.
This is a vicious cycle.

You may revise your model. Get rid of one of the links. Example:

```
public class Job
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual JobResult Result { get; set; }
}

public class JobResult
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Job Job { get; set; }
}

class JobResultConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<JobResult>
{
    public JobResultConfiguration()
    {
        HasRequired(e => e.Job).WithRequiredPrincipal(e => e.Result); // one-to-one
    }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new JobResultConfiguration());
    }
}
```

This will allow you to do:

```
Job job = new Job();
job.Result = new Result();
context.Jobs.add(job);
context.SaveChanges();
```

EF make one-to-one relationship: two entity with two entity with identical primary key.

More detail about Fluent Api: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx

Or your place revised model domain. As you circular links, i would try to get rid of the one link (or from Job or from JobResult)

Comment: I see.
What would you suggest me to do to solve this issue?
Also, why can EF not insert Job into the DB? JobResult is optional so can't it just insert 0 in JobResultId?

Comment: I see. However I would prefer to keep my operation as a single transaction. Is there really no way to accomplish this?

Comment: I updated my answer above. If you can give up one reference, the last option is what you need.

Comment: Removing one of the references seems like the best choice (although not what I had hoped for). If none of the fields were marked [Required] would I still not b able to insert them in a single transaction? I mean one-to-one relationships must be pretty common right?

Comment: Yes, you will still not be able to perform this transaction. You could execute this transaction on pure SQL. When designing the domain model is a good practice - minimize the number of links in the entities. This will simplify the mapping as well as the logic domain.

Comment: If you not used in domain logic property JobResult in Job entity then you will be better to get rid of this link.

Comment: The issue I see with removing the reference from Job is the fact that JobResult won't get added to the context when I add the job which makes it really impractical to implement IMO.

Comment: You can remote Job property in JobResult and save JobResult property in Job?

Comment: You can still choose a solution with call two SaveChanges method, but befor open transaction in context (context.Database.OpenTransaction()) and after last SaveChange call transaction.Commit().

Comment: Thnaks for your solutions. I think I will go with opening a transaction but would you mind explaining what you exactly meant with "remote the Job property" ?

Comment: I would in your place revised model domain. As you circular links, i would try to get rid of the one link (or from Job or from JobResult).

Answer (score 1):

Your `[Required]` field is on the wrong element for the type of operation you are performing.  Because you are Requiring a `JobResult` to have a `Job`, you can Create a `JobResult` and then create the Dependent `Job` (which has no requirements), but not the other way around.  If you try to create it from the `Job` end, the `Job` isn't attached to the `JobResult` until it is created, but it can't be created until the `JobResult` is, creating a circular reference.

Comment: I tried removing the [Required] from the JobResult.Job - however now I get this error message:

"Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values."

Comment: you may need to use the fluentApi to configure the order of operations.  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26389707/ef-code-first-one-to-one-relationship-multiplicity-is-not-valid-in-role-in-re/26425364#26425364

Comment: I've looked the thread through but I don't quite see how FluentAPI would apply as a solution in my case. Would you mind showing me an example?