# How to achieve one-to-one in code first approach if we have auto generated ids

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, one-to-one

I have those two entities:

```
public class User
{     
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string IdsrvUniqueId { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string About { get; set; }
    public GenderEnum Gender { get; set; }

    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}


public class NotificationSetting
{       
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public bool AutomaticallySubscribeToAllGroups { get; set; }

    public bool AutomaticallySubscribeToAllGroupsWithTag { get; set; }
}
```

what I want to do is implemente 1:1 relationship between them but currently with no success. I tried to use data notations and decorate them to look like this:

```
public class User
    {     
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        ..........

        // Navigation properties
        public virtual NotificationSetting NotificationSettings { get; set; }
    }

public class NotificationSetting
    {       
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [ForeignKey("User")]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        ....

        // Navigation properties
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }
```

It compiles, generates migration file but when I try to add new user I get an error.
Can you please tell me what is wrong here and How can I achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0):

I think the ForeignKey attribute is on the wrong property.

```
public class User
{     
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    ..........

    // Navigation properties
    public virtual NotificationSetting NotificationSettings { get; set; }
}

public class NotificationSetting
{       
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    ....
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    // Navigation properties           
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

That is how I always define them. The way you posted it, it uses the PK of NotificationSetting as the FK for User

Comment: What goes in the User entity? Aren't there any Data notations there?

Comment: User stays same as you had it. Updated my answer with both User and NotificationSetting

Comment: When  try to generate my migration I get this error: NotificationSetting_User_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'NotificationSetting_User_Source' in relationship 'NotificationSetting_User'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.

Comment: I think this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26389707/ef-code-first-one-to-one-relationship-multiplicity-is-not-valid-in-role-in-re

Comment: Unfortunately non of these works. I still don't know what's the reason for getting this error: A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column: 'Id'.

Answer (score 0):

When you configure entities to have one-to-one relationship, the key in your dependent entity(`NotificationSetting`) is foreign-key of principal entity(`User`) too, so it could not be auto generated field in database, so the `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` in `NotificationSetting` should be remove:

```
public class User
{     
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    ..........

    // Navigation properties
    public virtual NotificationSetting NotificationSettings { get; set; }
}

public class NotificationSetting
{       
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    ....

    // Navigation properties
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What I did was to remove both sides of auto generated id and it worked. I will also try this one.