# Entity Framework making incorrect PK-FK mapping on Code First migration

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

I have the following 3 classes set up to be created in a SQL Server database using Entity Framework Code First migrations. The **Survey** object is the main table.

```
public class Survey
{
    public int SurveyId {get; set;} //Primary Key
    public string Description {get; set;}
    public bool HasDevice {get; set;}
    public bool HasProcess {get; set;}

    public virtual Process Process {get; set;} 
    public virtual ICollection<Device> Devices {get; set;} 
}
```

Each Survey can have multiple **Devices** (1-to-many)

```
public class Device
{
    public int DeviceId {get; set;} //Primary Key
    public string DeviceType {get; set;}

    public int SurveyId {get; set;} //Foreign Key
    public virtual Survey Survey {get; set;}
}
```

Each Survey should have only one **Process** (1-to-0..1)

```
public class Process
{
    public int ProcessId {get; set;} //Primary Key
    public string ProcessInfo {get; set;}

    public int SurveyId {get; set;} //Foreign Key
    public virtual Survey Survey {get; set;}
}
```

The Fluent API mapping for these classes looks like this.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("Survey");
    modelBuilder.Entity<Survey>().HasOptional(x => x.Process).WithRequired(x => x.Survey);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Survey>().HasMany(x => x.Devices).WithRequired(x => x.Survey);
}
```

The problem is that when I apply the code first migration, the ForeignKey property in the Process table (1-to-0..1) keeps getting set to the `ProcessId` field rather than the `SurveyId`.  This means that every time I try to add a new Process record, I get the following error:

**The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Survey.Processes_Survey.Surveys_ProcessId". The conflict occurred in database "Backflow", table "Survey.Surveys", column 'SurveyId'.**

The 1-to-many mapping for Device works just fine.

I thought initially that this was due to having all my PK fields just say **Id**, but even after adding in the additional label part, it still makes the incorrect PK-FK link.  I have also tried avoiding the Fluent API by adding the DataAnnotation `[Key, ForeignKey("xyz")]` instead but it has the same result.  Recompiling the project, restarting Visual Studio, and even creating a new project and a new database do not help.

Is there something in the Fluent API or DataAnnotations that I am missing to get this to join correctly? Also, manually fixing the FK in the database *does make it work*, but that kind of defeats the purpose of doing everything in Code First with migrations.

Comment: `Process.ProcessId` is supposed to be both PK and FK when it's in a [1:1 relationship](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26425364/861716). Also when it's 1-0..1. So you should remove the `SurveyId` property.

Comment: @Gert OK, I'm confused.  If the `SurveyId` is removed from the Process object, what is it ForeignKey-ing to?  Will the ProcessID field just get the same ID as the Survey record has?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea, this uniquely ties it to the `Survey` it belongs to. This also means that `Process.ProcessId` is not an identity column.

Comment: @Gert I removed `Process.SurveyId` but still getting the same error as above.  I'm guessing that is because the `Process.ProcessId` field is empty, so there is nothing to match to `Survey.SurveyId`.  I thought that EF would handle that automatically like it does for the 1-to-many table.  Do I have to plug the SurveyId number into the ProcessId field manually, or is there something special I need to do to get it to pull from the existing survey?

Comment: Is this a modification from a previous schema?

Comment: I only modified the models and related code to remove the `Process.SurveyId` field.  Since this is just the stripped down "MCVE" version of my app, I removed and recreated the database. I didn't recreate all my views and controllers, just removed references to that field.

Comment: Of course existing Processes won't have primary keys that refer to Surveys (or at best only by coincidence to the right Survey). This requires a conversion of Process.SurveyId values to Process.ProcessId, which means: rebuild the table. Migrations isn't going to do that for you.

Comment: @Gert I passed the SurveyId value to the view and added a hidden field to hold it as the ProcessId and it works now.  If you would add your comment(s) as an answer I can accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fluent mapping of the 1-0..1 relationship is correct:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Survey>()
    .HasOptional(s => s.Process)
    .WithRequired(p => p.Survey);
```

But `Process` shouldn't have a `SurveyID` property (and column). In EF6, the *dependent* part of a 1-0..1 relationship (here: `Process`) is supposed to have a primary key that also refers to its *principal* (here: `Survey`) as foreign key. So `Process.ProcessID` is both primary key and foreign key. Thus, one `Process` is uniquely tied to one `Survey`.

By the way, in the other mapping, I would also mention the foreign key: if configuration is chosen over convention, it better be complete.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Survey>()
    .HasMany(s => s.Devices)
    .WithRequired(d => d.Survey)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.SurveyId);
```